# Overwrite characters in a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

When I type in this textbox, I need that the default behavior is overwrite, instead insert.
I don´t know if I made my self clear.

For example: I have a textbox with MaxLenght = 4. When it get focus, it need to overwrite chars, from the first to last.

I can do this using the "Insert" button. But I need an automatic solution.

Comment: I don't understand, what's your question?

Comment: try this EditingCommands.ToggleInsert.Execute(null, myTextBox);

Comment: This works. but I need more control over this "Toggle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using reflection by setting **`_OvertypeMode`** to **`True`** on **`TextEditor`** property of TextBox.

Suppose you have TextBox declaration in XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox"/>
```

and in code behind, you can do:

```
PropertyInfo textEditorProperty = typeof(TextBox).GetProperty(
                  "TextEditor", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

object textEditor = textEditorProperty.GetValue(textBox, null);

// set _OvertypeMode on the TextEditor
PropertyInfo overtypeModeProperty = textEditor.GetType().GetProperty(
               "_OvertypeMode", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

overtypeModeProperty.SetValue(textEditor, true, null);
```

Source - [MSDN link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a38c6aec-81a2-4b1c-9a77-c0ae890c1363/how-to-force-a-textbox-to-have-insert-mode-off-in-wpf-4-vbnet?forum=wpf).

Answer (score 1):

You could try handling the key down event, for example:

```
private void MyTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int myCaretIndex = MyTextBox.CaretIndex;
    char[] characters = MyTextBox.Text.ToCharArray();

    if (myCaretIndex < characters.Length)
    {
        characters[myCaretIndex] = char.Parse(e.Key.ToString());

        MyTextBox.Text = string.Join("", characters);

        MyTextBox.CaretIndex = myCaretIndex + 1;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```